# Problem on wpdb queries, wp_insert_post, wp_insert_user etc. The query runs twice

Tags: query, wpdb, wp-insert-post

Anyone encountered this issue?

I have created a custom php script which adds a new post by using `wp_insert_post()` but everytime I run the code it creates a 2 new post where in it should be only be one, its like it runs twice, so I tested another function using `wpdb->query` and its also the same its really weird. Please help I dont know what causes and how to fix this issue.

Thank you very much.

Here is a sample code i did just to test the issue and it still creates 2 identical post

```
   function testtest(){
      $ads_data = array(
            'post_title'    => "test",
            'post_content'  => "test",
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'ads',
            //'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $ads_id = wp_insert_post( $ads_data );
}add_shortcode('testtest','testtest');
```

**SOLVED**

I have figured it out now, whats causing the issue is on my header.php it is this line of code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'favicon' ) ); ?>" />
```

I find it really weird, i have no idea why that line of code is causing the issue, anyway thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the context of your code, where does it run, what action is it hooked to?

Comment: @Milo i just created a shortcode to run it, ive edit the code now

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Or have you tried running this code with a basic WP install?

Comment: @czerspalace ive disabled all my plugins, and its still like that, this wasn't a problem actually before with my other sites. Maybe ill try with a basic wp install, thanks

Comment: your code inserts a single post when I test it, so a guess would be that more than one request is hitting the page containing the shortcode. this is obviously not a safe way to execute code, you should be taking steps to insure something runs once if you only want it to run once.

Comment: @Milo This wasn't an issue with my previous sites, that's why i find it really weird why its happening, Thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my similar issue (see below code block) by modifying the path to wp-load.php. Actually I used Frankie Jaret's uri parse script which really only works on the default install but, meh, that's what I use. I'm sure you can find a function that will parse it out where ever it may reside. Code below

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

I don't know if this will help you out but it solved the issue for me.

**Similar Issue:** I realize this isn't an answer but I can't make a comment since this is my first post and I have 0 rep. But I have this *exact* same problem I just started to see it recently and have no favicon issues as I run the insert from a cronjob. I've been able to replicate it at least 30 consecutive times today. I will post the answer once I've figured it out. But I do know for a fact only the specific number of post arrays are being passed yet it still creates two posts, or customs in my case.